# Netmask of the network class of minimum size

Tags: network-programming

Given two IP addresses, let's say 112.119.240.17 and 112.121.120.19, find the netmask of the network class of minimum dimension/size that would contain them both.

So the problem I am facing is that I don't quite get this exercise. I know how to get the broadcast and the network address if I am given the Netmask, but I'm not sure if that helps me here. I know that there are 5 address classes and I know how they're categorized, and I think that the network address is a multiple of the class' dimension, and that the dimension of the class is a power of 2, but I'm really at a loss on how to approach this exercise. I've been going through course notes and been bothering Google all day with this, could someone give me some hints?

Comment: You have to find a network mask that contains both. So you know the first Octet (Byte) is part of the network mask becaue both numbers are equal: 112. In the second Byte you have to find the binary representation and then find the bits that are equal until the first one different. Then you will find out the complete network mask.

Answer (score 0):

This question is asking you the CIDR(Classless Inter-Domain Routing) knowledge. Those fixed length network classes are obsolete and are replaced by the CIDR technology. In CIDR, An IP address is part of a CIDR block, and is said to match the CIDR prefix if the initial n bits of the address and the CIDR prefix are the same. The CIDR can effectively use the IP addresses, as well as make the route work more efficiency by route aggregation. You can get the CIDR knowledge from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

When you get the knowledge CIDR, the question will become simple:

112.119.240.17
**1110000 0111**0111 11110000 00010001

112.121.120.19
**1110000 0111**1001 01111000 00010011

==> **1111111 1111**0000 00000000 00000000

The netmask is 255.240.0.0/12

Also I find this picture from the wikipedia is helpful:
[image]